# crystal report how to display date in boxes of Bank Check Book

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I want to print check from SAP Business one. I do all setting except the bank check Date have issue. in bank check  the date is in boxes and having spacing.

can any one help me to how can i do it?

[image]

Comment: You want to do same in crystal? Is this your requirement?

Comment: YES SIR THIS IS MY REQUIREMENT

Comment: Dont use all caps in international community it is considered as shouting

Comment: ok sir how can i do that in crystal report . i do all thing except the date with spacing with fit the boxes.can u help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Siva reccomended (or similar) ---

8 separate formulas

left(totext(Currentdate,'dd'),1) //d1

right(totext(Currentdate,'dd'),1) //d2

left(totext(Currentdate,'MM'),1) //m1

right(totext(Currentdate,'MM'),1) //m2

left(totext(Currentdate,'yyyy'),1) //y1

mid(totext(Currentdate,'yyyy'),2,1) //y2

mid(totext(Currentdate,'yyyy'),3,1) //y3

mid(totext(Currentdate,'yyyy'),4,1) //y4

Place in report and format each to have top, bottom, left and right borders.

Comment: thanks @CoSpringsGuy  this is fulfill my requirement

Answer (score 0):

take as mnay formulas as many characters in date and in each formula take one date character and display all formulas side by side.

you can extract single chracters ny conveting date to strings.

after placing all formulas side by side, Apply borders for those formulas.

Comment: i convert my date to string totext({chewckdate})  now how can i replace  the first character then second i do it with left function but can't work

Comment: i can write this function    Left(totext({@dt}),1) its give me first value from left when i Left(totext({@dt}),2) this its give me first 2 values from left but i need second value onlye one value how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

For PLD in SAP Business One use the following formula

F_108==>
Document Date

F_195==>
Substring(Concat("0",Day(F_108)),Length(Concat("0",Day(F_108)))-2,Length(Concat("0",Day(F_108)))) **--> Day  2 result is 02 & for day 28 result is 28**

Substring(F_195,0,1) **-->Extract the left digit & used to display in cheque i.e 0 or 2 from the above example**

Substring(F_195,1,2) **-->Extract the right digit & used to display in cheque i.e 2 or 8 from the above example**

Do the same for month by replacing the Day() with Month()

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you